# How to set different columns for document set than the files within it?

Tags: 2013, document-set, site-column, metadata

When adding a **document set** I want it to require: owner & project type.

Inside the document set **each file** within it requires: file type (owner & project type are already shared), but *not* on the Document Set as a whole.

How do I set up different columns for files within data set than the columns in the library where the document set is housed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom content type that inherits from whatever sort of document you want to contain in these document sets (ie a new Word Document content type called Project Word Doc that inherits from Word Document). Add on to that the additional columns you want and mark them required.

Then create a custom content type that inherits from Document Set. When building that, add into the document set settings the content type (or types) that you created above.

Go into your document library's advanced settings, turn on Allow Management of Content Types. Add the custom document set there.